# Does c# using statement need assignment?

Tags: c#, using-statement

At first I had some code like this:

```
WindowsIdentity otherIdentity = // got that from somewhere else
WindowsImpersonationContext context = otherIdentity.Impersonate();
Ldap.DoStuff();
context.Undo();
context.Dispose();
```

Knowing that `WindowsImpersonationContext` implements `IDisposable` and `Dispose()` also calls `Undo()`, I think I should be using `using` instead:

```
using (var context = otherIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    // Run as other user
    Ldap.DoStuff();
}
```

Now, ReSharper correctly notices that I am not using `context` and suggests to remove the assignment. Does this also work? To what code does it expand at compile time?

```
using (otherIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    Ldap.DoStuff();
}
```

Comment: To test whether this works, build and run.

Comment: @adv12: It will 'work' either way regardless if the object is disposed or not, and the garbage collector disposes it at some point anyway. But even if `using` is disposing it, I wonder how. Does the statement keep an unnamed reference of the expression result? Of all expression results? The documentation never mentions that...

Comment: I would consider using `try-finally` instead of `using` here. The revocation of impersonation is important and should be emphasized in the code, not hidden.

Comment: Also, as I always remind people who are doing impersonation: if the `DoStuff` can throw then any *exception filters* in the caller will run *before* the `finally` or `using` calls `Undo` or `Dispose`. That means that the code in the filter will be run in a context that impersonates the other user, which might not be what you want.  The safest pattern is to use `try-catch-finally` where both the catch and finally do the `Undo`.  So that's another reason to not use `using`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can omit the variable in a `using` statement, and the compiler will automatically introduce a hidden variable as if you had written

```
using (var temp = otherIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    Ldap.DoStuff();
}
```

except that you can't access `temp` in the body of the `using` statement.

Curiously, this syntax doesn't seem to be documented in [MSDN Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx). Instead, refer to the C# specification:

> A using statement of the form
>
> ```
> using (ResourceType resource = expression) statement
> ```
>
> corresponds to one of three possible expansions.
>
> [...]
>
> A `using` statement of the form
>
> ```
> using (expression) statement
> ```
>
> has the same three possible expansions. In this case `ResourceType` is implicitly the compile-time type of the `expression`, if it has one. Otherwise the interface `IDisposable` itself is used as the `ResourceType`. The `resource` variable is inaccessible in, and invisible to, the embedded statement.